# decimal minutes in "real" minutes

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From $8:45$ to $8.75$, it's easy. $\frac{45}{60}= 0.75,$ plus the $8$ hours is $8.75$.

How can I go from $8.75$ to $8:45$?

I didn't find anything in the internet and I am not a math genius.

Comment: $$\frac{45}{60}=0.75 \quad\leftrightarrow\quad 60 \times 0.75 = 45$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a division to convert from one form to the other, do multiplication to obtain the opposite.

$$8.75 =8 \text{ hours} + 0.75 \text{ hours} = 8  \text{ hours} + 0.75 \times 60 \text{ minutess}$$

Answer (score 0):

For a number like 8.75, the part before the decimal is the number of hours (**8**), and if you take the part after the decimal  (**.75**) and multiply it by 60, you'll get the number of minutes ($.75 \times 60 = 45$). Altogether, the resulting time is is $\mathtt{8:45}$.

The reason this works is because we're asking 8.75 is how many hours plus how many minutes? It's 8 hours plus 0.75 additional hours. To represent those additional hours as minutes, we multiply the additional hours by 60 minutes. The result is that 0.75 hours corresponds to 45 minutes. So altogether, 8.75 hours is 8 hours plus 45 minutes.